# Does a constexpr move constructor ever make sense?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, move-constructor

Does it ever make sense to have a `constexpr` move constructor?

For example, consider the following:

```
#include <array>

class C
{
public:
    constexpr C(std::array<int, 3> ar) : m_ar{ar} {}
    constexpr C(C&& other) : m_ar{std::move(other.m_ar)} { }
private:
    std::array<int, 3> m_ar;
};

int main()
{
    constexpr C c1 {{{1, 2, 3}}};
    constexpr C c2{std::move(c1)};
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't compile, since despite calling `std::move` on `c1`, the compiler deduces it needs to use the (implicitly deleted) copy constructor, not the move constructor. I'm not sure why.

But if I remove the `constexpr` from `c1`, then it becomes unusable by the `constexpr` move constructor.

Is there any way to get this to work? Or is this a bad example for a `constexpr` move constructor, but there are good examples? Or, is it just always wrong to have a `constexpr` move constructor?

Comment: With `constexpr C(const C&& other)`, it compiles since C++14.

Comment: @Jarod42 But it likely doesn't actually move anything, since you can't move from a const object. It becomes merely an unnecessarily complicated copy constructor.

Comment: @Jarod42 Huh. It does. How come? I would expect `std::move(other.m_ar)` to fail since `other` is a `const C&&` (since it compiles, I expect it *does* move `other.m_ar`, unless it does something sneaky instead such as copying `other.m_ar` instead).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, a move constructor can be used with a non-`const` object whose lifetime started during the evaluation of the constant expression:

```
// C++14
constexpr int f() {
    C a(/* ... */);
    C b = std::move(a);
    return 0;
}
constexpr int i = f();
```

Similar things can be done in C++11, e.g.

```
constexpr C foo(C&& c) { 
    return std::move(c); 
}

constexpr int f() { 
    return foo(C()), 0; 
}
```

That said, since everything used in a constant expression is required to be trivially destructible, the usefulness of a move constructor is rather limited.

Comment: Interesting! I guess this means move constructors could become more useful in the future when (if?) non-trivial destructors are allowed in constexpr expressions. Is there any example which comes to mind where it *could* be useful for a class with just a trivial destructor?

Answer (score 2):

> This doesn't compile, since despite calling `std::move` on `c1`, the compiler deduces it needs to use the (implicitly deleted) copy constructor

`c1` is of type `C const`. When you `move()` it, that's really a cast to rvalue reference, so you get a `C const&&`. Note that it's still `const`. When we perform overload resolution, there are three constructors:

```
C(std::array<int, 3> ); // not viable
C(C&& );                // not viable
C(C const& ) = delete;  // viable!
```

`C const&&` can't bind to `C&&` for the same reason that `C const&` can't bind to `C&`. We're left with just the copy constructor, which is implicitly deleted.

---

Having a constexpr move constructor could make sense - but the object you're "moving" from can't really be moved from, because it's presumably `const`. You could add a `const` move constructor:

```
constexpr C(C const&& other) : m_ar(other.m_ar) { }
```

This is a glorified copy constructor, but it allows the syntax you want. May as well just allow copying.

Comment: Which probably means that my move constructor above becomes sneakily wrong if I make its parameter `const&&` but keep the code `std::move(other.m_ar)`, since it would just copy the array, not move it.

Comment: In any case the purpose wasn't to make my syntax work, the bigger point was if it ever makes sense to actually have a constexpr move ctor.

Comment: @Danra It's not wrong. Moving doesn't *have* to be something other than copying.

Comment: A `constexpr` move constructor can be used in a non-const object whose lifetime started during the constant expression evaluation: `constexpr int f() { C a(/*...*/), b = std::move(a); return 0; } constexpr int i = f();`.